# detecting double free object, release or not release

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management

If we have this code in our interface .h file:

```
@interface CarModelSelectViewController : UITableViewController {

NSString *fieldNameToStoreModel;
NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
DataEntered *dataEntered;


}


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *fieldNameToStoreModel;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain) DataEntered *dataEntered;


@end
```

In our implementation file .m we must have:

```
- (void)dealloc {

[fieldNameToStoreModel release];
[fetchedResultsController release];
[managedObjectContext release];
[dataEntered release];

[super dealloc];
}
```

The 4 objects are assigned from a previous UIViewController, like this:

```
UIViewController *detailViewController;

detailViewController = [[CarModelSelectViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
((CarModelSelectViewController *)detailViewController).dataEntered = self.dataEntered;
((CarModelSelectViewController *)detailViewController).managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
((CarModelSelectViewController *)detailViewController).fieldNameToStoreModel = self.fieldNameToStoreModel;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
```

The objects that now live in the new UIViewController, are the same as the previous UIViewController, and I can't release them in the new UIViewController ?

The problems is that sometimes, my app crashes when I leave the new UIViewController and go to the previous one, not always. Normally the error that I'm getting is a double free object.

I've used the malloc_error_break but I'm still not sure wich object is.

Sometimes I can go from the previous UIViewController to the next one and come back 4 or 5 times, and the double free object appears.

If I don't release any object, all is working and Instruments says that there are no memory leaks ...

So, the final question, should I release those objects here or not ?

Thanks,

m.

edit:

the fetchedResultsController.delegate is always nil, as in this view the fetched objects doesn't change, and the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate is not in the @interface .h file.

edit 2:

Added the declaration propoerties of the interface file, sorry!

Comment: Are the first two code snippts from the DetailViewController files? What do your property declarations look like? If you don't retain the object, you shouldn't release it either...

Comment: I've added the propoerty declarations, thanks for saying it!

And yes, the first two code snippt are from the *new* DetailViewController

Comment: In your header file `interface.h` you have the ivar and property declarations switched. i.e. ivars should be within the braces, and `@property` declarations below them, outside the braces

Comment: ohhorob: you're right, it's a mistake copy&paste, now it's ok. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care about an object, you retain it. If you retain it, you release it. This is all of the law, the rest is just commentary.

Most likely you are incorrectly declaring your @properties and are failing to include the "retain" attribute in them.

Note that you should be declaring `detailViewController` as a `CarModelSelectViewController*` rather than declaring it as a `UIViewController` and then casting it every time you use it.

You should read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt), and specifically [Practical Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html). Cocoa memory management is actually quite simple. If you always use accessors and learn the [three magic words](http://robnapier.net/blog/three-magic-words-6), you will seldom have much trouble.

Comment: I don't think the cast UIViewController is important here, but as your suggestion, I've refactored and used directly the CarModelSelectViewController, but the problem persists.

Those objects must be retained during all life of the viewController, that's why I release them in the dealloc phase.

Using the assign instead of retain simply doesn't work ...

Also, I can go back and forth from the same viewcontroller until I get the double free object. 

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are correct to release them in your `dealloc` method.  It seems that they are being over released somewhere else.  I recommend you use Instruments with `NSZombieEnabled` turned on.  (Use the Object Allocation instrument, click on the 'i' button, and check "Enable NSZombie detection".  I believe it requires you to use the Simulator for that.)  When the zombie is found you can track the life of the object and see exactly where it's being retained and released.

Comment: I'm using the Enable NSZombie detection and Record reference counts, the app crashs but no zombie is detected ...
How they can be over release outside their ViewController ? thanks

Comment: When you set them on the view controller, I can see that they also exist as ivars on the old one.  It seems that there are multiple references to these objects, so it the over release could be happening somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing any custom initialization for `CarModelViewSelectController` it would be useful for us to see that.

Also, is your `UINavigationControllerDelegate` doing any memory management?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found it :-)

Once the malloc_error_break has been enabled, XCode stopped where the error was with the addres of the object, a print of the object in the console gave me the exact object, and this object wasn't in those views that I was releasing, so the problem was in the very first view that was calling my subsequent views ...

thanks,

regards,

m.